# Lagrangian with a boundary contribution, external work and interaction

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, boundary-conditions, boundary-terms

I am considering a linear second order partial differential equation of the form
\begin{align}
F(q,p)&=-a\,q-\nabla\cdot p=0\\
p(q,\nabla q)&=b\cdot\nabla q
\end{align}
with $a$ scalar and $b$ a symmetric matrix. Multiplying the equation by $q$ and integrating over the domain I have
\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega\left(-a\,q^2+\nabla q\cdot b\cdot\nabla q\right)dV=\int_{\partial\Omega}q\,p\cdot n\,dS
\end{equation}
where $n$ is the outward normal.
The bulk term is (related to) the energy content of the domain, while the boundary term is (related to) the work at boundary. I would say
\begin{equation}
L=\frac{1}{2}W
\end{equation}
where $L$ is the Lagrangian and $W$ is the work done externally. Is it right?
What about two PDEs interacting through a common boundary, what is the total Lagrangian?